# Open source face recognition for Android

Tags: java, android, face-recognition

Using Android, what are the open-source option for face recognition.

Comment: check out the open CV (Computer Vision) library Android port @ http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android

Comment: @Roshan Wijesena which approach you used? I used opencv and its working but the output i want to get is like if i scan my face in beard and next scan my picture w/o beard it must be scan and recognize. but currently i am getting its recognizing same face as it scanned prior.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here are some links that I found on face recognition libraries.

- Android's [FaceDetector.Face](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html)

  - Tutorial: [Implementing Face Detection in Android](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/10/28/implementing-face-detection-in-android)
- [OpenCV Facerecog](http://sites.google.com/site/elsamuko/c-cpp/opencv-facerecog)

Image Identification links:

- [Moodstocks](https://moodstocks.com/)
- [Ltutech](http://www.ltutech.com/)

Comment: A couple more links:  http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui08/  and  http://code.google.com/p/javafaces/

Comment: You can also do expression recognition using http://face.com/

Comment: @A.Abiri any tutorial of Ltutech ? i m stuck how to use this SDK I downloaded and imporeted in my eclipse. now how to send request from my android for face recognition

Comment: is this still up to date?

Comment: Yes, most developers today still use either the Android SDK's built-in face recognition API or OpenCV for face recognition.

Comment: I'd like to add,  that 'Face Recognition' is different from 'Face Detection'. What A.Abiri answered is all about FaceDetection

Comment: Moodstocks has joined Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Microsoft's Face API. It can detect and identify people. learn more about face API [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/).

Answer (score 0):

[macgyver](https://askmacgyver.com) offers face detection programs via a simple to use API.

The program below takes a reference to a public image and will return an array of the coordinates and dimensions of any faces detected in the image.

https://askmacgyver.com/explore/program/face-location/5w8J9u4z

Comment: He asked about face recognition

Answer (score -1):

You use class **media.FaceDetector** in android to detect face for free.

This is an example of face detection: https://github.com/betri28/FaceDetectCamera

Comment: He asked about face recognition