# Face detection in Android system

Tags: android, android-gallery, face-detection

I have a question regarding where the face detection informaition is stored by Android.
There seem to be two options :

1) The face detection information is stored along with Image as a part of EXIF metadata.

2) Android stores the detected faces information somewhere and retrives when user opens that particular image.

For option 1 I tried to fetch information with Metadata Extractor but there was no tag in particular that corresponds to face detection (correct me if I am wrong)

If it is option 2 how exactly I can filter gallary images according to faces tagged inside ?

Please give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android have [face detection api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html). You can just call [findFaces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html#findFaces%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.media.FaceDetector.Face%5B%5D%29) method for bitmap. Also you cat use external libs and frameworks like [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825778/face-recognition-api-for-java-android). According your points - which framefork you use for face detection?

Comment: The face detection APIs will return Face objects which has information like Eyedistance ,pose ,confidence etc. I am not interested in that. All I want is the "Contact Name" which the user has already tagged in the photograph previously.Currently I am not using any external library.

Comment: i think you definetly need external library as android facedetection does not support what you want. i think you need face recognition not face detection. face recognition is completely different from face detection.  face detection detects the faces in a picture but face recognition recognises the face in the picture which you need now.