# Use android face detection after loading image from gallery

Tags: android, api, imageview, detection

Heyy, i'm trying to make an android app where the user selects an image from the gallery and after that the image appears in an ImageView and a box appears over the faces detected.

I already have the code for loading an image from the gallery and put it into the ImageView, the only problem is that i dont know how to detect the faces from the loaded image.

Any examples??
Any hlep would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of recognizing faces in Android. You'll need to implement something like [OpenCV library](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html). If you look at it you'll find a simple example!

Also, you can look at [JJIL Library](https://code.google.com/p/jjil/)

[This question has been answered here already.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825908/2823516)

EDIT:
It seems that there are built in classes like [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) and you can see an example on how to use them [here](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html)