# Android/Java Face Recognition: gender, age, emotions

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, face-detection, face-recognition

Is there any simple library/framework for Android/Java which can detect a face on a picture and give me some information about the person on the picture? I mean information like gender, age, emotions (smiling, sadness, anger) ...

I have tried [Face++](http://www.faceplusplus.com/the-first-face-java-program/) and Microsoft's [Project Oxford](https://www.projectoxford.ai/). It works great but I would want to use something like that without the Internet connection.

The [features in Google Play Services](http://www.sitepoint.com/face-detection-in-android-with-google-play-services/) look great but it gives me only the smiling probability, not the age, gender etc.

Comment: Try OpenBr. http://openbiometrics.org/ or check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825778/face-recognition-api-for-java-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Android library for face detection and cropping.
The library is compatible with  both java and kotlin language.

It has the following features:

- Prominent face detection
- Multiple face detection
- Automatic face crop
- Face classification information
- Age classification support

Referee the [Viola SDK](https://github.com/darwinfrancis/viola) for the implementation details.

Example

```
val viola = Viola(listener)
viola.addAgeClassificationPlugin(context) //optional, available via external dependency

viola.detectFace(bitmap)

private val listener: FaceDetectionListener = object : FaceDetectionListener {

        override fun onFaceDetected(result: Result) {}

        override fun onFaceDetectionFailed(error: FaceDetectionError, message: String) {}
}
```