# Implementing Facial Recognition authentication in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement **Facial authentication in Android**. I can see **Android SDK** has **Face Detector API** where I can detect the faces. But is there any API which can be used to authenticate the user on basis of **Facial recognition**. 
For Example, I have put my Face as a password in Android and now I need to write code to check the face data which I have stored while locking my Android device.

Regards,
Munish

Comment: Refer  this [face-recognition-library-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318517/face-recognition-library-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have seen these sites and links already but these are third party tools and does not really solving the problem. I am checking Android face authentication. I appreciate your help but I need to know if Andoid has any Face recognition api for authentication like it has for Biometric(thumb impression) authentication.

Comment: as of my experience, there is no any application using facial recognition in their app by using android's default facial recognition.

Since majority of android device has no facial recognition feature (as one of a default lock screen function).

I also suggest 3rd party library as it not cause much difficulties for end-user by just setup the facial authentication for first time usage only.

Comment: openCV is the best option for  Facial recognition

Comment: @Ganesh Thankyou and I am usimg the same.

Comment: @Munish i want to implement same thing, can you please help me, i have an app which can authentic with face auth, so i have set and face unlock on device setting and now want to implement same face unlock for my app

Comment: @Pankaj: I have not implemented Face authentication as I did not find any good stuff on internet. You can check below links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825778/face-recognition-api
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624090/face-unlock-using-confirm-credentials-api

Comment: Android Q with include facial auth into the Biometric API according to this developer blog post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/introducing-android-q-beta.html

Comment: Thanks Brad, I have stopped working on this solution. But i will give a try to check about Android Q.

Comment: did anyone found how to implement face recognition using androidx Biometric API?