# Face recognition authentication in android

Tags: android, security, authentication, face-recognition, biometrics

Similar to fingerprint authentication for apps, i am trying to implement face recognition authentication in one of my android app. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve the same using any library or anything.

Comment: have you achieved this task?

Comment: anyone did achieved this feature in android ? please share any helped resources regarding face recognition in android apps

Answer (score 5):

**Android’s Face Recognition** (Software) is *less safe than* **Apple Face ID** (Hardware)
Because of

- It doesn’t work in poor lighting conditions
- It is possible to unlock a phone with a picture

So, it’s more a convenience as a *feature* than a *security*.

Comment: 100% correct , beside ,  face recognition has already show field for to many raison , as twins case , pictures ,  present of galsses  , etc 
i was working on an app for security with Oauth2 and fingerPrint + face recogniition , we drop the face side becouse is not a "big deal " 
in my vision , even the apple face ID is not working well  
that why you can focus on passwords ( tokens ) , + fingerprint( to 50% )

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go for **Android Face Detection API / Vision API**

check for the [documentation & tutorial](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial)

find the same on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

There is also an [library](https://github.com/kairosinc/Kairos-SDK-Android) which I had heard about but I haven't tested it

You can have option for going with **Firebase's new introduction:** [Firebase ML kit](https://firebase.google.com/products/ml-kit/)

Find documentation for ML kit >  [Face Recognition here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces)

Comment: Just a remark: Currently MLKit can **NOT** _recognize_ faces, it can only _detect_ them. That is not the same thing. If you want to add recognition on top of MLKit, I suggest using TensorFlow or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to develop a real accurate Face authentication (such Apple's FaceID or Samsung's Face Recognition), try to find if you can access their API. If they don't open their API, you can't do it.

But, as starter, maybe you can use Azure's Facial Recognition. [Read more](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/?v=18.05)

Or if you simply just want to detect faces, you can also use Firebase ML Kit. [Read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces)

Comment: Its realy helpfull your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Use android Biomatric api which is introduced in android 9