# Android face recognition login

Tags: android, face-recognition

I want to implement face recognition login for my application.

My Question is does android support it? does it provide any API for the same?

If so is there any sample available?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733793/face-recognition-authentication-in-android

Comment: check this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825778/face-recognition-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the Tensorflow Lite to build something similar.

I'd suggest taking a look at the following blog series to see how it can be done : https://medium.com/devnibbles/facial-recognition-with-android-1-4-5e043c264edc