# Detect device is secured with pin lock or fingerprint lock of face lock?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

My application contains user authentication for login(includes pin/pattern, fingerprint unlock) which depends on device security. I am using Biometric manager to detect whether device has fingerprint support using **BiometricManager** and also checking whether device is secured using **isDeviceSecure()**. I am in need to detect in which mode mobile device is secured whether pin/pattern with, pin/pattern with fingerprint, pin/pattern with face unlock or all the three modes(pin/pattern, face unlock, fingerprint).

Comment: maybe you will get an answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409969/how-to-check-device-compatibility-for-finger-print-authentication-in-android

Comment: @Priyankagb The solution provided is to check whether fingerprint is enrolled or not. I need to check in which mode the device is secured.

Answer (score 2):

here is the code to detect what lock type is set

add lib to `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta01'
```

and this code to your activity

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean keyguardSecure = keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure();
Log.e("---", "checkSecurityTypes: keyguardLocked - " + keyguardSecure);//true = pin/pattern

int i = BiometricManager.from(this).canAuthenticate();
Log.e("---", "checkSecurityTypes: " + i);//true 0 = pin/pattern with finger print

switch (i) {
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
        Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.");
        break;
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.");
        break;
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.");
        break;
    case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
        // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
        break;
}

if (i == 0 && keyguardSecure) {
    //fingerprint is always with pin/pattern/password
    Log.e("---", "checkSecurityTypes: fingerprint is set with pin/pattern");
} else if (keyguardSecure) {
    //true if pin/pattern/password is set
    Log.e("---", "checkSecurityTypes: pin/pattern is set");
}
```

we can't detect face type. for more see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48796941/10989990)

Comment: I have tested your solution its working but even the fingerprint is disabled for device security, I am receiving "i=0(BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS)" in samsung galaxy device. As disabling fingerprint as device security, Fingerprint data not cleared from device(BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS is triggered when using BiometricManager.from(this).canAuthenticate()). Also, I need the device current lock mode(pin/pattern, face unlock, fingerprint).

Comment: We can't get a specific lock type which one is currently set up.

Comment: I am having the scenario, If user disables fingerprint from the device security, App needs to detect it ask only other mode of authentication like pin/pattern instead of fingerprint using biometric prompt.

Comment: this method `createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()` from `KeyguardManager` might help you. try it and check what is returning.

Comment: No, Can't able to get the required information.