# how to know in android if a user unlocked his device with pin/password/fingerprint/face?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In android can we get if the user unlocked his phone with either of below method:

1. PIN
2. Password
3. FingerPrint
4. FaceID

Comment: Did you find: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#determine-how-user-authenticated

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the question. I want to know if the user has unlocked the device with either of those methods to perform the next action based on that data.

Comment: So a duplicate of: [Detect device is secured with pin lock or fingerprint lock of face lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65474598/295004) and it seems it is not possible to get how the user unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPasswordSucceeded` callback function from `DeviceAdminReceiver` services in native and hbrid both. This function triggers when user correct PIN code.

```java
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    
    @Override
    public void onPasswordSucceeded(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent, @NonNull UserHandle user) {
        super.onPasswordSucceeded(context, intent, user); // Your Code here    
    }    
}
```