# How to check if user has unlocked device with the biometrics or PIN/Password?

Tags: java, android, security, biometrics

I am trying to figure out if user has unlocked the device with the traditional **PIN/Password** method or with the biometrics like **Face unlock** or **Fingerprint**.
I tried some answers out there like https://stackoverflow.com/a/28694962/10357086 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451916/10357086.

I'm still unable to get the exact solution for this. Is it possible to do so? And if it is, then how would I get it?
All the answers I found are either about implementing the biometric authentication or about showing a fingerprint authentication dialog whenever needed.

But I don't want that. I want to check how the device was unlocked by the user?

**TL;DR** : I just want to know if the device is unlocked with the biometrics or PIN/Password method so that I can perform the next action based on it in my app.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Detect device is secured with pin lock or fingerprint lock of face lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65474598/295004) and it seems that apps can't get information about how the user unlocked the device.

Comment: Not the exact duplicate. I don't want to know what type of the security user has set on his phone, but I want to know if he unlocked the device with the PIN, Password or Fingerprint. 
Though, As you are saying that there is no way to do it, then it seems fair after trying many solutions and looking on many places for the answer. Thanks.