# Face Authentication like Finger Authentication in Android

Tags: android

I want to develop an Application in which it must use system fingerprint and face authentication to unlock the Application. Successfully done with Fingerprint authentication. But not finding any libraries or code for face authentication in Android.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825908/6344335

Comment: `not finding any libraries ` you know that you should not ask for a library here, right?

Comment: Here I don't want to recognize the face, I want to use system face authentication like fingerprint authentication.

Comment: Did anyone found how to implement face recognition using androidx Biometric API?