# How can I use FaceDetectionAPI without google play Service in android AOSP?

Tags: android, api, face-recognition, google-vision

I am currently developing Face Detection Application in an Android marshmallow AOSP without Gapps. But I can't use Google Vision api without Google Play service. So, is there any way to use Google Vision api without Google Play Services? Or, I'll thank you if you let me know another good api!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use it without Gooogle Services.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825908) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, here are some alternatives to Google Vision API.

1. [Microsoft Computer Vision](https://english.api.rakuten.net/microsoft-azure/api/microsoft-computer-vision) probably comes the closest in terms of endpoints functionality.

If you're looking for positional data on detected faces, try [Lambda](https://english.api.rakuten.net/lambda/api/face-recognition-and-face-detection) or [Animetrics](https://english.api.rakuten.net/animetrics/api/animetrics-face-recognition).

Answer (score 0):

[Android Face Detection Example](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/android-face-detection-example/)